# Facebook app canvas page keeps refreshing on Internet Explorer (IE7)

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer

I am building a facebook app. So far it works well on Firefox, Chrome, and even IE8. But for some reason when I load the app on IE7, the canvas page keeps reloading automatically and doesn't allow me to navigate to the other pages in the app. Any suggestions on how I can fix this would be much appreciated.

Cheers